# Transpose pandas Styler

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, pandas-styles

I would like to style my data for some data analysis. This works well with `df.style`, which I have only recently discovered. I seem to be missing one crucial aspect, however: how can you transpose a Styler *after* you have applied methods to it? This is useful when you want to use the column names with `subset` methods.

So, the following code works well; it colors cells in the A and C columns. Now I want to transpose the axes so that I get four rows (and index removed).

```py
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

def set_style(v):
    if v > 0:
        return "background-color: #ff887c;"
    elif v < 0:       
        return "background-color: #93d9ad;"
    
df2.style.format(precision=2).applymap(set_style, subset=["A", "C"]).hide_columns()
```

Unfortunately adding `.T` does not work because

> 'Styler' object has no attribute 'T'

Is there a way to do this, that is, transpose a `Styler` object after all other processing has been done?

Comment: Why don't you transpose `df2`, then apply `style`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Then I can't use `subset`.

Comment: I'm finding that doing df.T.style doesn't work, at all. For example. df.style.bar().hide().to_html() gives me bars for data, and hidden indices.  When I do the same thing with df.T (i.e., df.T.style.bar().hide().to_html()) I get no bars, and the indices show.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely correct, but `pd.DataFrame.style` can be thought of as an HTML-formatted string, so it doesn't have a transpose operator.

You can transpose the data and use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) to slice rows:

```
df2.T.style.applymap(set_style, subset=pd.IndexSlice[['A','C'],:])
```

Or you can re-write your function to take in the rows and check on the name:

```
def set_style_row(r, sub=[]):
    if r.name in sub:
        return np.where(r>0, "background-color: #ff887c;", "background-color: #93d9ad;")
    return [''] * len(r)

df2.T.style.apply(set_style_row, axis=1, sub=['A','C'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I guess your second option with `r.name` is what I was looking for. Can't believe I missed that rows have a `name`. Could you explain a bit more how the IndexSlice works - what it does? And perhaps, if possible, which on you'd guess is faster? (My assumption being that the `if` check isn't very fast.)

Comment: All info in the user guide on subset slicing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control-with-Slicing