# pandas styler doesn't work on transposed df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just want my data to display with bars and run horizontally instead of vertically.
But when I switch from df to df.T, all the style info goes away:

Sample code:

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from IPython.display import HTML, display

input = "Please go to the store and get some milk"
words = input.split()
weights = [0.4,.9,0.15,0.0,.8,0.05,.93,0.05,.98]
df = pd.DataFrame({"word":words, "weight":weights})
display(HTML(df.style.format(precision=3).bar(vmin=0,vmax=1).hide().to_html()))
display(HTML(df.T.style.format(precision=3).bar(vmin=0,vmax=1).hide().to_html()))
```

Output:
[image: sample output showing bars on vertical display but not horizontal]
Notice how the second version doesn't display any colored bars, and displays the (unwanted) index numbers (now column names) on the top.  I want the first version, just horizontally.

I've been trying various combinations of supplying subsets and changing axes, using `.apply()` and/or `.applymap()` with some new styling function I define (e.g. iterating over rows), but everything I've tried either gives me error messages or doesn't have any effect.

For example, the code

```
display(HTML(df.T.style.format(precision=3).bar(subset=['weight'],axis=1,vmin=0,vmax=1).hide().to_html()))
```

yields the error message "`KeyError: "None of [Index(['weight'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`" (and changing to axis=0 doesn't help.)

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Related posts (but it didn't help me):
[Transpose pandas Styler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250156/transpose-pandas-styler)

Comment: I think the `bar` applies on numeric dtypes only. In you case, you can set the `word` to the column of the transposed data: `df.set_index('word').T.style.bar(vmin=0, vmax=1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang  Boom!!!  That was it. Thank you!   If you'd like credit for an Answer, please resubmit your comment as an Answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is best solved in the way mentioned by [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) in the comments:

```
df.set_index('word').T.style.format(precision=3).bar(vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

But let's find out why the first way didn't work and how can we force it to work as intended. Here's the thing, `bar` can accept a 2d input as its values, see `help(df.style.bar)`:

```
subset : label, array-like, IndexSlice, optional
    A valid 2d input to `DataFrame.loc[<subset>]`, or, in the case of a 1d input
    or single key, to `DataFrame.loc[:, <subset>]` where the columns are
    prioritised, to limit ``data`` to *before* applying the function.
```

Which means, that we can print `bar` for only one cell if needed:

```
df.set_index('word').style.bar(subset=('go','weight'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

If the subset is a string, bar assumes that it is a column name (*columns are prioritised*). That's why you see `KeyError: None 'weight' index are in the columns` when the real `weight` index is now a row index, not a column name.

One way to overcome this is to pass the row name as a tuple:

```
df.T.style.bar(subset=('weight',), vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image: bar plot]

In this case, bar assumes, that the first element of a tuple is a row index, and the second, if present, is a column name. If it's a tuple with only one element, then bars should be drawn along the mentioned row.

In case if we want to draw bars on a subset of rows, then we pass this subset as a list or slice in a first item of a tuple. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(1, 1+4*4).reshape(4,4), 
    index=[*'xyzw'], 
    columns=[*'ABCD'])

# use only `y` and `w` to draw bars
display(display(df.style.bar(subset=(['y','w'],), vmin=0, vmax=16)))

# bars on an intersection of selected rows and columns
display(df.style.bar(subset=(['y','w'],['B','D']), vmin=0, vmax=16))

# bars on all rows from `y` to `w`
display(display(df.style.bar(subset=(slice('y','w'),), vmin=0, vmax=16)))
```

[image: bars example plots]

---

More [about indexing and selecting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-slicing-with-labels)